# show top and bottom menu after click textbox in cordova

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I use cordova and set app to fullscreen.
when user click the textbox to type, andoid show the keyboard and show top and bottom menu. after unfocused from textbox, top and bottom menu is visible and have overlap with application.

How can force android to don't show these menus and show only keyboard?
OR how can hide these menus?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, may be help you

**Add statusbar plugin**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Then on **keyboard hide event** set statusbar hide like

```
window.addEventListener('native.hidekeyboard', function(){
    StatusBar.hide();
});
```